Why can my app open websites when the app is open, but not when it is closed. Even though it always opens the website via a foreground service?
In my application users are able to have a service running in the background that after a certain amount of time opens a website for them. But when you close the app and the timer runs out the website does not open. You can see that the service is still running (foreground service so there is a notification). When the app is still open the website does open.
val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(website))
browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(browserIntent)


You cannot launch activities from the background on modern versions of Android except in very restricted circumstances.

Thank you for your reply! I will look into the few circumstances that would allow this and see if any of them are applicable to my app.

Looking through all the options available I do not believe any of them would work for my app, however I did find an app that does open links while not open (macrodroid). Does anyone maybe have a clue on how they are doing it?
